# typewrite(),press() on pyautogui is not working on Remote Desktop

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, pyautogui

I am using my host where i used to connect to the Remote machine where i want to fetch some data.
I am using pyautogui for press operation and typewrite() to enter some values.
The remote server is configured and application i want to operate will be always open when i connect to remote machine.

I am able to login through pyautogui.

after that when i write below code:

```
pyautogui.press('esc')
pyautogui.press('f1')
pyautogui.typewrite("T")
```

Its not typing T on the application that is opened on remote server.
Please suggest me some python way so that i can overcome from this issue.

Thanks
Simun

Comment: Usually you have to copy your script to remote machine. You also have to keep RDP window open and not minimize it. There are few workarounds though. Just follow the link on this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51079677/3648361) and further you can find how to automate some steps (in GitHub issue). I'm planning to write some guide on that. But had no chance yet.

Comment: It seems like keyboard module in python solved my problem. I am interacting with remote application using the image recognition mechanism using pyautogui. whenever i need keyboard interaction i am using below code.  "keyboard.write("some string") and keyboard.press("enter")".It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

go and change the type of the keyboard , i faced the same situation by typing a full url in ubuntu terminal , **i solved by changing the type of keyboard in the system to US**