# Installing and running pywinauto in a remote desktop

Tags: python, remote-desktop, pywinauto

I want to automate a very old software (drafix) that can only be run in Windows XP, on a remote desktop.

Would it be possible to write a pywinauto script that would directly interact with the software controls, without the need to send mouse/keyboard clicks on the GUI, and then minimize the Remote Desktop screen or even lock the PC?

I need to open the program, loop through a list of file names, open each one of them and save as a different format.

I did it with some basic GUI automation - clicking on buttons if necessary, sending keyboard shortcuts and entering the file names form a list. But it isn't very reliable, and I would like to minimize the Remote Desktop window and use my PC instead of having it in the foreground.

From what I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299472/pywin32-pywinauto-not-working-properly-in-remote-desktop-when-it-is-minimized), it should be possible with some workarounds, and I would need to install an older version of Python (any idea which one?) on the remote desktop to write and run the script there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is just copying your script to remote machine and run it there. Regarding minimized or closed RDP there are few workarounds and tricks described in the [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html) which summarizes few StackOverflow answers.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I want to use SWAPY or py_inspect to correctly identify the controls, and do the debugging on the machine, without having to move the script back and forth between the machines

Comment: RDP doesn't provide any GUI elements info to local machine. So in your case all debugging should happen on remote machine only.

Comment: By the way, you have to uninstall comtypes on Windows XP: `pip install pywinauto`, then `pip uninstall -y comtypes`. This is needed because `UIAutomationCore.dll` is not present on WinXP so `backend="uia"` is not available. If you need `backend="uia"`, you have to install .NET Framework 3.5 or later available for WinXP.

Comment: I have managed to make it work - used swapy to inspect the controls, and programmed them on my own machine, then just used pyinstaller to prepare an executable.

The real challenge was making it work on XP - but your hint about comtypes helped, had to add `--hidden-import comtypes, comtypes.gen,comtypes.patcher, comtypes.GUID` to the pyinstaller options, and prepare everythin in a 32bit Python 3.4 environment - miniconda helped here.

Thank you Vasily!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm planning to fix it in the library later: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/703

Answer (score 0):

There is other way that you can control gui application on remote Desktop with pywinauto. You can use rpyc or Remote Python Call. that is a python library for rpc(remote procedure call)

`https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/`

your remote computer is as server and your host is as client in rpyc.

first you you need to run rpyc_classic.py in remote computer after connect to it and use pywinauto library. for example i use  rpyc for start microsip on remote computer with pywinauto.

ip of remote computer is 192.168.222.222.

```
import rpyc
ip = "192.168.222.222"
conn = rpyc.classic.connect(ip)
conn.execute("from pywinauto import Application")
conn.execute(r"Application().start(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\MicroSIP\microsip.exe')")
```